# Plesk Uninstall Memory issue

Tags: yum, low-memory

I am trying to uninstall plesk from my VPS by running following command:

```
yum remove sw-* psa-* plesk-*
```

When I run this command I get following error:

```
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
memory alloc (4 bytes) returned NULL.
```

First time when I run above command, this mem alloc (4 bytes) was very big number like (67864987). then I Googled it, got some clear/ulimit commands. Executed them. Rebooted my system. Stopped all processes and executed this command again but still getting 4 byte issue. Don't know how to get rid of it.

I also tried ulimit after reboot but no success and Yes. No swap attached. These are stats of my system:

```
[root@vps ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           384         67        316          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:         67        316
Swap:            0          0          0

top - 21:01:07 up  3:12,  1 user,  load average: 0.24, 0.08, 0.03
Tasks:  31 total,   2 running,  29 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    393216k total,    69832k used,   323384k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k cached
```

Is there any other alternative to achieve my goal to uninstall plesk? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebooting your system undoes everything you set with `ulimit` - Raising the limits is effective for the current session only.

Absent more information about your configuration we can't help you, we can only take wild guesses in the dark.
My wild guess: Your VPS does not have sufficient RAM allocated to it to run the yum/rpm removal process, and probably doesn't have any swap configured.
Either:

- Remove the packages one or two at a time (which may or may not solve the problem)
- Have your provider allocate more RAM to your VPS (and pay them accordingly)

Comment: Yes. You are right. my VPS didn't have sufficient memory for this process. so i left using that system.